# IE8 is not supported on this operating system

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, installation, internet-explorer-9, downgrade

I am using vista. I had IE7 installed on it. Few months ago, I upgraded it to IE9 because I needed it to test few things on it.

As now I am done with IE9, y'day I decided to remove it. It wasn't so easy. But from some help on internet I successfully removed it (I don't remember the links).

I have IE7 again now. Now I need IE8 to test few other things. I downloaded IE8 from microsoft and when I tried to install it. I got an error that "IE8 is not supoorted on this operating system". On microsoft site there is written that IE8 is supported on windows vista and windows 7.

Have you guys ever downgraded your internet explorer? I heard there are problems with downgrading. But I couldn't find any solution to it.

Need your help.....Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you use virtual machines to test various operating system / browser combinations.

Comment: yes. I am using vmplayer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are constantly testing various versions of IE (like every web developer out there strongly dislikes doing) you can try the [IE Platform Preview](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/info/downloads/) that lets you switch between various versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

"  Now I need IE8 to test few other things "

I think u can download and use [IE TESTER](http://www.debugbar.com/download.php)
which gives all ie versions

Comment: I can't. because there is no IE developer tool for it. Also my experience with IE-Tester is that is not 100% exact like original IE. Moreover I haven't found a way to do script debugging in it. In my project I have to test across 2-3 windows and in such windows menu, title, status bars are all set to disabled. I am finding it difficult to do testing in original versions of IE. How can I prefer IE-Tester, which is even more harder.